# Is it possible to restrict Deja Dup backup by network?

Tags: backup, deja-dup

I want to restrict Deja Dup backup of my laptop to only my home network. It's not a big deal as it just fails if I'm working somewhere else but I wonder if it still possible to do?

Answer (score 0):

Déjà Dup is a very simple backup program for very simple users...

And guess what? *You're not a simple user any more!*  **;-)** Time to look out for a [more sophisticated backup program](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2596/comparison-of-backup-tools)!  **0:-)**

I would use [Borg](https://askubuntu.com/a/1148760/344926) and have 2 scripts:

- one in the `Startup Applications` that connects to your NAS and doesn't connect to it if you're not on your home network
- one in `crontab` that does a daily / weekly backup if it's connected to your NAS.

<sub>**Note:** This is how I run...</sub>